How to get bash-like editing and history with stdin.read() or input()?
I have a command line tool which repeatedly gets input from the keyboard using stdin.readline().
When i type some text at the prompt i only have limited possibilities for editing, such as moving the cursor (left and right) and deleting a character.
But, for example, if i move the cursor to the start of my text and type character, it is appended at the end of my input.
Also, when i type the up key, the cursor actually moves upwards.
Is it possible to endow the python standard input with editing and history (accessible with the up and down key) like for instance bash?

See: the readline module.


Is it possible to endow the python standard input with editing and
history (accessible with the up and down key) like for instance bash?

I suggest taking look at cmd, which is part of standard library, consider following simple example
import cmd
class MyShell(cmd.Cmd):
    intro = 'Welcome to tiny calculator. Type help or ? to list commands.\n'
    prompt = '(calc) '
    accumulator = 0
    def do_add(self, args):
        'adds integer value to accumulator'
        self.accumulator += int(args)
        print("Current value is", self.accumulator)
    def do_subtract(self, args):
        'subtracts integer value from accumulator'
        self.accumulator -= int(args)
        print("Current value is", self.accumulator)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyShell().cmdloop()

beyond browsing command history (UP and DOWN arrows) it does also provide command autocomplete e.g. you might write sub, then hit TAB, then write value and it will give same result as writing subtract followed by value.

The library that bash uses to do this is the GNU readline library, which Python includes as part of the standard distribution:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html
A search term you might find useful is 'REPL', which stands for Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop, which is basically what bash or any similar tool does.
